# laravelffmpeg color filter effects

Tags: laravel, ffmpeg-php

How can I apply a color filter effect in my video using laravel-ffmpeg package and what is the proper way to do it?

The package have a custom filters but i dont know how to translate the ffmpeg command for color filter to laravel-ffmpeg.

From FFMPEG cmd

```php
"eq=brightness=0.3:saturation=1.3:contrast=1.1"
```

To LARAVEL-FFMPEG package

```php
->addFilter('eq=brightness=0.3:saturation=1.3:contrast=1.1')
```

And I saw that there are `-vf` in custom Filter in laravel-ffmpeg package, so i try to use the ffmpeg cmd command for color filter, I dont know the proper way to use it in laravel.

Here are my code with `EncodingException` error

```php
FFMpeg::fromDisk('videos-temp')
        ->open('buck.mp4')
        ->export()
        ->toDisk('videos-temp')
        ->addFilter('eq=brightness=0.3:saturation=1.3:contrast=1.1')
        ->inFormat(new \FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264)
        ->save('sample.mp4');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should try to use the [`custom`](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg/blob/master/src/FFMpeg/Filters/Video/VideoFilters.php#L164-L169) method.

Try something like:

```php
use FFMpeg\Filters\Video\VideoFilters;

///
->addFilter(function (VideoFilters $filters) {
  $filters->custom('eq=brightness=0.3:saturation=1.3:contrast=1.1');
})
```

or maybe:

```php
->addFilter('eq', 'brightness=0.3:saturation=1.3:contrast=1.1')
```

I haven't tried it, I'll let you reply in comments if it doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you! It works. I get it now. Now I need to read the documentation of FFMpeg. Thank you for sharing your knowledge :)

Comment: Glad I could help you :)